# "Search all sites" returns no results regardless of search term

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com

Currently, there is a bug in the [search feature](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test) on stackexchange.com. Namely, it always says that "Your search returned no matches." regardless of which term I type into the "Search all sites" box.

So now, we need to get the bug fixed so that "Search all sites" works properly again.

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate that this broken as I use it often when new users post here on MSE to give them a search result that provides potential better sites for their question and/or to find their answer themselves. If I have a say in priorities I would suggest this one needs to be near the top of the bug list.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I can see the issue in the logs but won't be able to resolve it until Monday

Answer (score 9):

[m0sa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/156631/m0sa) just pushed a build that fixes this. We added some metric handling in the search code but stackexchange.com didn't have metric handling configured correctly so was hitting a null reference when running the search across all sites.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this. Having the ability to search all of SE at once is quite helpful. It's something I commonly use at least a few/several times per day.